# Training two networks simultaneously with keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Let's say one wants to train two slightly different networks simultaneously with the same dataset.
A way to go is through the functional API: https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/.
Here is how it would work on a simple architecture (just two multilayer dense networks with same input/output):

```
same_input = Input(shape=(n_feat, ), name='input')

x = Dense(n_feat//2, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu')(same_input)
x = Dense(n_feat//128, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='elu')(x)
x = Dropout(dropout_val)(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Dense(n_feat//256, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu')(x)
x_out = Dense(out_dim, kernel_initializer='normal', name='output_x')(x)

y = Dense(n_feat//2, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu')(same_input)
y = Dropout(dropout_val)(y)
y = Dense(n_feat//128, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='elu')(y)
.... (some difference)
y = Dropout(dropout_val)(y)
y = BatchNormalization()(y)
y_out = Dense(out_dim, kernel_initializer='uniform', name='output_y')(y)


model = Model(inputs=same_input, 
             outputs=[x_out, y_out])

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss={'output_x': 'mean_squared_error',
                   'output_y': 'mean_absolute_error'},
              loss_weights={'output_x': 1,
                            'output_y': 1.})

model.fit({'input': X},
         {'output_x': Y, 'output_x': Y},
         epochs=fit_pars['num_ep'],
         batch_size=b_size,
         validation_split=valid_split,
         callbacks=callbacks,
         verbose=2)

network_predict = np.array(model.predict(X_test, batch_size=b_size))
```

However, **I am not absolutely sure whether this is correct, and whether there is a way to do it right on Keras.** The total loss that is used to optimize the network will be the sum of the two losses, and that imposes an interference between the two networks.
**Can someone tell if this is right or wrong, and whether there is a way to train the networks independently yet concurrently?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your approach. Let's say you have two networks `N1` and `N2` with loss functions `L1` and `L2`, respectively. When you use a combined loss function `L=L1+L2`, the gradient of `L` wrt. a parameter `w` in `N1` is the same as the gradient of `L1` wrt. `w` if and only if `L2` doesn't depend on `w`. The same thing applies for any parameter `w` in `N2`.

Therefore, when you use your combined loss function to optimize your networks `N1` and `N2` with a gradient-based method such as RMSprop, you should be getting the same updates as if you were optimizing `N1` and `N2` independently, since your two networks have different parameters (i.e. they don't share weights).